# Jmeter - using jmeter function as bsh.args

Tags: java, jmeter, assertions, beanshell

I'm trying to send a function as a parameter in bealshell assertion component. 
the parameter is

```
${__V(SB_names_${counter})}
```

it's basically a dynamic string that is different in every iteration. 
I'm trying to access this parameter by

```
vars.get(bsh.args[2]);
```

since it's the 3rd parameter in the list, but I keep getting null.

[image]

is it possible at all to use jmeter function as parameter? or is the problem is with getting the parameter?
Thanks.

Comment: I've done something similar before by putting the function i wanna call in a bash script and calling it like so ${__BeanShell(source("function.bsh"))} . maybe it will help you.

Comment: show how your BeanSHell assertion looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work fine just:

1. Make sure the variable is defined
2. Remove all commas from "Parameters" section
3. Remove all extra whitespaces from "Parameters" section.

As a workaround you can consider getting the desired value from `vars` object which stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) like:

```
String sb_name = vars.get("SB_names_" + vars.get("counter"));
```

Demo:

[image: Beanshell function]

Also consider moving to [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language as it is better from performance perspective. See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-performance-youve-been-waiting) guide for more information on groovy engine installation and scripting best practices.

Comment: Thanks! the vars.get("SB_names_" + vars.get("counter")); did the work. for some reason it didn't work with the bsh.args[2].